# Create sql table with utc datetime column

Tags: sql, datetime-format

I've created a view in which I convert datetime to UTC and it works fine, Here is just a part of my view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[ERROR] as 
SELECT [ERROR_SEQ]
  ,Convert(varchar,CAST(GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' AS 
   DATETIME),120) AS DATE_ERROR
```

But how can I do it when I create an SQL table?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (GETDATE() etc are product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a computed column:

```
alter table error add date_error as
    ( convert(varchar(255),
              GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time' as datetime,
              120)
    );
```